# Cannot achieve to change Configuration (locale) at runtime (running activity)

Tags: java, android

I'd like to change the locale on my app (runtime).It works fine so far. The only thing left is refreshing the current activity.

The documentation says that updating the locale Configuration should restart the running activity (same behavior as the screen orientation) but it does restart it in my case. (I did not use the `android:configChanges="locale"` to prevent this behavior).

Here are the key parts :

I have my activity :

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    //....
}
```

An Adapter where I bind a click  (inside the getChildView function) :

```
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//...
 convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

                convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        I18N.setLang(context, "fr");

                    };
                });
}
```

And the setLang method inside my I18N class : 
public class I18N {

```
public static void setLang(final Context context, String langCode)
{
    if (langCode.equals(""))
        return;
    try {
        final Locale newLocale;
        final String[] languageRegion = langCode.split("\\-(r)?");
        I18N.saveLocale(context, langCode);
        newLocale = languageRegion.length > 1 ? new Locale(languageRegion[0], languageRegion[1]) : new Locale(languageRegion[0]) ;
        current = newLocale;
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = new Locale(languageRegion[0]);
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("exception", e.getMessage() + e.getClass());
    }
}
```

}

I have tried this. It kind of works but I don't like this idea of refreshing the activity manually.
The main issue is that despite using the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`, the history (using the back button of the mobile device) does not work properly (each click on the list to change the language still create an history) :

```
Intent refresh = new Intent(context, context.getClass());
refresh.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
context.startActivity(refresh);
```

What am I doing wrong ? How can I either make the updateConfiguration restarts the activity or make the manual intent not create an history ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relaunching the activity, you want to setContentView() once again after you change locale to change activity layout, or reinflate the fragment

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        I18N.setLang(context, "fr");
                        //setContentView(R.layout.act_layout); // for activity
                        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null)
                    };
                });
```

**edit**

Your convertView would be final so you can refresh it through a method

```
protected View refresh()
{
    //inflate
    View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    //setup ui controls
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                    I18N.setLang(context, "fr");
                    refresh();
                    };
            });
    return convertView ;
}

public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    return refresh();
}
```

Comment: This may be a good lead however I have the error : "accessed from within inner class needs to be declared final" and I cannot set final View convertView in the function declaration since it said :" cannot assign a value to final variable"

Comment: I have set view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null) but it does not change anything.

Comment: Thanks you. There are many type of cells in my listView. It means that I have to inflate the View for every one of them (they use a different layout) ?

Comment: Yes you need to inflate each different layout after changing the locale

Answer (score 0):

I have added  `android:noHistory="true"` to my settings activity in the AndroidManifest.xml

This way, i can go back to the main screen after changing the language.